# Using malloc in C doesn't work

Tags: c, malloc

I have a problem with C malloc function when I write:

```
int *ptr = malloc( sizeof(int) );
```

or this

```
int *x = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int*));
```

or this

```
int *x = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

error: 'x' : 'int *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'

I am using Visual Studio 2013, Win32 Console Application.

What could be the problem?

Comment: `int *ptr = malloc( sizeof(int) );` is the right one

Comment: So why doesn't it work?

Comment: removed the C++ tag - not necessary

Comment: @0x90: One could argue that the truly right one is `int *ptr = malloc( sizeof *ptr )`.

Comment: @Nityuiop18: Possibly it doesn't seem to work because: A) You're not copying and pasting the actual code that generated the error and instead typed from memory. B) The error corresponds to a different line. C) Your code generated other errors during compilation before this one.

Comment: It is hard to believe that all these variants produce the same error message. Only the first one will typically produce something like that, if `malloc` is undefined. And in C code this would typically be a warning, not an error. Apparenty, the information you posted is inaccurate.

Comment: @EdHeal: Are you use it was not necessary? I have a feeling OP was probably actually writing C++ (or the compiler was treating the code as C++ despite OP's intent), and the error was coming from that... But it's hard to tell with fake code.

Comment: R - One does assume that using `malloc` is C (I guess that is the intention). `new` for C++. But I concur that using fake code one needs to make a leap of faith

Comment: Include stdlib.h? Maybe he's ignoring the line just above where it says 'warning - assuming return type default int' or something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
int *ptr = malloc( sizeof(int) );
```

and

```
int *x = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

Are essentially the same (you do not need the cast)

Both allocate enough memory on the heap to store an int, and return a pointer to it.

This, however, is ....?

```
int *x = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int*));
```

Rubbish

The problem is to write sensible code.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way of allocating memory for an int on the heap:

```
int *ptr = malloc( sizeof(int) );
```

So you should not have any error. If you forgot to include the header `<stdlib.h>`, you should have a warning only. But I am not familiar with visual studio. Also, please check that you did not misspelled the word `malloc`.